# Installing Appwork admin theme - Sass::SyntaxError in Home#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed the theme Appwork to cloud9 ruby on rails as a new application however when I run the server and open the app browser page i get this, why am I getting this error? (I am new to rails)

```
    Sass::SyntaxError in Home#index

    Showing /home/ec2-user/environment/rails-starter/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #19 raised:

    ile to import not found or unreadable: ../../../../node_modules/vegas/dist/vegas.

    Load paths:
     /home/ec2-user/environment/rails-starter/app/assets/config
      /home/ec2-user/environment/rails-starter/app/assets/images
      /home/ec2-user/environment/rails-starter/app/assets/javascripts
      /home/ec2-user/environment/rails-starter/app/assets/stylesheets
      /home/ec2-user/environment/rails-starter/vendor/assets/fonts
      /home/ec2-user/environment/rails-starter/vendor/assets/javascripts
      /home/ec2-user/environment/rails-starter/vendor/assets/libs
      /home/ec2-user/environment/rails-starter/vendor/assets/stylesheets
      /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/coffee-rails-4.2.2/lib/assets/javascript
      /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actioncable-5.2.0/lib/assets/compiled
      /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activestorage-5.2.0/app/assets/javascripts
      /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/actionview-5.2.0/lib/assets/compiled
      /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/turbolinks-source-
    5.1.0/lib/assets/javascripts
      /home/ec2-user/environment/rails-starter/vendor/assets
      /home/ec2-user/environment/rails-starter/node_modules
```

Comment: Does the file it mentions exist? Do you need to run `npm install` again, and in the right folder (the one that it thinks 'node_modules' exists in)? Or has it got the path wrong, i.e. your node_modules is somewhere else?

Comment: Thank you for the reply I have fixed the problem, the node_modules were not installed, I installed them individually, stupid mistake! :)